# sftp script to login to the server

Tags: php, linux, bash, phpseclib

I am using a script to login to the server using sftp with keys. I am getting the below errors while accessing the server using the script. Errors are as below :

```
: No such file or directory
./new.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token \`'SSH_HOST','
'/new.php: line 2: `define( 'SSH_HOST', 'IP_Address' );
```

See below the script I am using :

```
<?php
define( 'SSH_HOST', 'IP_Address' );
define( 'SSH_PORT', 7475 );

define( 'SSH_PUBLIC_KEY', '/home/test/test_sftp.pub' );
define( 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY', '/home/test_sftp.ppk' );
define( 'SSH_USERNAME', 'test55' );
define( 'SSH_PASSWORD', 'lkdlkdsf' );

//define( 'SSH_USERNAME', 'test5654' );
//define( 'SSH_PASSWORD', 'dfsfsd45' );


set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include_once('Net/SSH2.php');
include_once('Net/SFTP.php');
include_once('Crypt/RSA.php');
include_once('Crypt/Hash.php');
include_once('Math/BigInteger.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$pubKey = file_get_contents('id_rsa.pub');
//$rsa->setPublicKey($pubKey);
$priKey = file_get_contents(SSH_PRIVATE_KEY);
$rsa->loadKey($priKey);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP(SSH_HOST, SSH_PORT);

if (!$sftp->login(SSH_USERNAME, $rsa)) {
    echo 'error:';
        print_r($sftp->getLog());
    exit("Login Failed\n");
}
echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
//$sftp->put('filename.ext', 'Hiiii!');
```

Comment: It was my error. I used `./script.php` instead of `php script.php`.
But the login is still having some issues. Now getting 
`error:Login Failed`

Comment: You're calling $sftp->getLog() but haven't enabled logging. You need to do this by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

For debugging define complex log constant right after including `Net_SFTP` class and print log and sftp errors:

```
include_once('Net/SFTP.php');
define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
...
if (!$sftp->login(SSH_USERNAME, $rsa)) {
    print_r($sftp->getSFTPLog());
    print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
    exit("Login Failed\n");
}
```

Then you'll get detailed log output. Hope this helps. Otherwise update question with detailed log output, then will be easier to give you right answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo in the question.. I have corrected it. Still issue is there

Comment: Sorry Alexander,  
It was my error. I used ./script.php instead of php script.php. But the login is still having some issues. Now getting error:Login Failed

Comment: Got the below errors:
`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ssh in /home/test/new.php on line 31`
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSFTPLog() on a non-object in /home/test/new.php on line 31`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) Fixed.